# Using CEWP to apply css to a table on sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, css, cewp

I am in the process on adding css to a CEWP for a table within a webpage. I have tried different CSS and nothing is working.

It is a basic table that just needs the border black due to the border lines are clear now.

If anyone can help Im thankful

Comment: add !important to every CSS element.  It is recommended to add css in script editor.

Comment: add your code to your post

Comment: Why not just add it to the html (e.g. <table border="1">)?

Comment: Apply css with proper class to table & put your CEWP at the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks I have added the following code below and i have also used jsut a script editor

Comment: .ms-rteTable-default{ border:1px solid $borderColor:#000000  margin: 8px 0; }

Comment: Thanks everyone i figured out with everyone comments by going to SPD and just linked  a style sheet from there.